How can I let devs upload test APKs without accessing prod signing key?
The goal is to restrict public release process to the trusted folk.
Maybe I don't need to restrict the signing key and there's another form of fine-grained access control available?
The issue is - it has to be the same app to be able to test the same subscriptions and whatnot.

Why do you need to upload it? Can't the testers install the apk's directly?

@KonstantinKotenko I don't think they would be able to test subscriptions if the APK is not distributed through Play Store.
